# What do the decimals mean before the Z in datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

If I have the datetime string `2016-07-19T21:55:48.298Z`, what does the `.298` stand for?

Comment: Milliseconds. You'd be down to micro if you had six decimals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times

Comment: @YannVernier that should really be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milliseconds. You'd be down to micro if you had six decimals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times

As answered in the comments by @yann-vernier